# Is there a way to censor an input in python?

Tags: python, input

I'd like to write a program with a login, but I don't want others to see the password. So can I let it get censored somehow?

Comment: [**`getpass`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is! Take a look at [getpass.getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html)